# Windows 8 'News' app seems to be missing the 'My News' option

Tags: windows-8

When I right-click the screen in the Windows 8 *News* app, all I see is `Sources` and `Worldwide news`; no `My News` section. I can’t seem to add any new sources or change any of the existing views.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What version is it? (on the Charms bar, go to Settings => About) What  language is it set to? Which country are you in? (The News page in the store says `Note: Some features and enhancements may not be available in all markets`)

Comment: I was not using the US locale. Seems to work better now that I switched the locale.

Comment: Seriously? You've got to be in the US locale for this to work? That's absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **My News** section is there, see the video at [Windows 8 guide: How to use the News app](http://www.computeractive.co.uk/ca/pc-help/2202897/windows-8-guide-how-to-use-the-news-app).

The relevant part of the video says:

> Right-click on an empty part of the screen, and click *My News*.

After right-clicking, a menu appears:

[image]

---

If the **My News** section does not appear, then try to change your application content region/language to US (source [News app - Can't change/delete/add sources](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/news-app-cant-changedeleteadd-sources/66da7325-7ced-4611-a1d4-00aa13292bf3)).

> Please add the my news option for all regions or the ability to add own feeds to it, otherwise tha app is useless outside the us.
>
> -DieterDWorks *In reply to YETWO post on September 18, 2012*

---

> 1. Open News app
> 2. Press Windows + C
> 3. Go to "options" and change "App language and content to" to some other setting and restart the news app
>
> -YETWO

Comment: Like I said, when i right-click the screen, I only get 'Sources' and 'Worldwide (English)". Also no Bing story of the day or Bing news or whatever.

Comment: I appreciate the screenshot, but as I said, I don't have "Bing Daily" or "My News" there, only "Sources" and "Worldwide (English)".

Comment: @efdee - This sounds like a regional problem.

Comment: Changing the locale to the US fixed the problem. Kind of sad. But at least I can set the locale for the News app separately. Thanks!